# "Network path not found" when trying to access network PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, network-shares, home-networking

I have 2 computers: Windows 7 desktop and Windows 8 laptop in a home wi-fi network. They are both configured to use passworded shared file access, not homegroup-based access. Desktop PC can access laptop, but laptop throws "Network path not found" when trying to access the desktop (which is visible in the network on laptop).
Ideas?

Comment: try to share some folder inside of desktop folder

Comment: Try turning the firewall off on the desktop?

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: I think you can't share desktop, or maybe it's shown by default but not shared, I didn' check it so I'm not sure. So that's why i said that :) But I know realised that i didn't read the guestion carefully and by desktop he meant desktop pc :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Kasperky settings->Firewall-Networks and set LAN to either local or trusted, ensure internet is set to public.

Comment: It wasn't that simple. I had to fiddle with firewall tunings and unblock some protocols. Don't remeber the details, but it was fairly obvious once I found firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem was in the firewal. Once I turned Kaspersky Internet Security off, everything started working.